# How to download a zip file from api using axios with response like Content-Type: multipart/form-data Content-Disposition: attachment;fileName=d.zip

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I'm developing a function using axios in vue 2 that download a zip file from the api providing from server side, and the response header like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2023 07:19:12 GMT
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment;fileName=d.zip
```

,
my solution is like below:

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
link.href = `example api`;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

my question is here:
the size of zip file is like 100MB, and the browser sends the request and then browser will not start to download until the zip file is downloaded in background, how can I improve this, thanks very much!